# remove names of several objects in R

Tags: r, rename

I have many irregularly named objects whose names, in order to be able to use some other package, I need to set to `NULL`.

E.g.,

```
v <- 1
w <- 2
names(v) <- "hello"
names(w) <- "world"
```

I can write

```
names(v) <- names(w) <- NULL
```

but for succinctness I would prefer something like

```
names(c(v,w)) <- NULL
```

which however does not work ("`Error in names(c(v, w)) <- NULL : could not find function "c<-"`). This is not unexpected, of course - from `?names`: it is a function "to get or set the names of *an* object".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to place it in a `list` and set the `names` to NULL.  It is better not to have multiple objects in the global environment

```
lst1 <- lapply(list(v = v, w = w), setNames, NULL)
```

Also, as @joran mentioned, `unname` can be used as well or `as.vector` (which remove the attributes)

```
lst1 <- lapply(list(v = v, w = w), unname)
```

If the intention is to change the already existing objects,

```
list2env(lst1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
v
#[1] 1
```

It is better not to create multiple objects in the global env

Comment: There's also an `unname` function that might be useful in this context.